# How to install Tomcat 6 from a zip?

Tags: tomcat

I have extracted the zip package in my home folder and I want to access webapps folder through localhost:8080, which files I have to change in order to get this done?

I have installed java-6-sun, paths JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH are set.

Edit: I work on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO Mitch's answer looks like it has a little error in it, assuming that Lunar did not unzip to /usr/share/tomcat6. If you are installing from the zip, then you should not be using `/usr/share/tomcat6/bin/startup.sh` instead you should be using `$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/startup.sh` where $TOMCAT_HOME is the directory that you unzipped into.
If you continue to have problems, please enter $TOMCAT_HOME and issue the following commands, and show me the output

```
pwd
sh bin/startup.sh
cat logs/catalina.out
```

Then, please attempt to load `http://localhost:8080` and tell me the result seen in the browser.

Comment: Hi Oyrm, I am aware of this paths thing. The output of pwd: `/home/lunar/tomcat`, the output of second command is: `Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/lunar/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/lunar/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/lunar/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        .:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/lunar/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar
`,

Comment: the output of the 3rd is too big. But shutdown.sh returns this: `Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/lunar/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/lunar/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/lunar/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        .:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/lunar/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar
./catalina.sh: 425: ./catalina.sh: .:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java: not found`

Comment: Startup.sh looks good, Immediately after you run startup.sh please do try to load http://localhost:8080 and tell me exactly what you see. Also, please find a way to share that log. I recommend using http://pastebin.com/

Comment: localhost:8080 - Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8080. Oyrm what log details would you like to see?

Comment: The phrase "can't establish a connection" means you can't attach as a client to port 8080. Either the startup is failing, thus not binding to 8080, or the startup is succeeding and binding to 8080, but you have a firewall blocking 8080 and preventing clients from attaching.
Any error messages in the log. I don't know what's wrong, so I'd prefer to see the full log if at all possible. If not, then please do read the log and tell me if you see any errors.

Comment: https://rapidshare.com/files/1629004917/log.txt - output of the 3rd comand

Comment: Oyrm sorry for being a pain but that log you are talking about... where can I find it?

Comment: I see that you've done quite a lot more than just unzipping this installation. It appears that you've added a number of servlets. JDBC errors and NullPointer Exceptions related to those servlets are being thrown, though, all of these exceptions appear to be dated
    28-May-2012 08:08:01 or earlier
Is your clock mis-set or am I looking at the wrong log file ?

Finally, we see in the log many similar messages to
    ./catalina.sh: 375: ./catalina.sh: .:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java: not found
which java version do you intend to use ? Is $JAVA_HOME set to point to this version ?

Comment: Make sure that we're looking at $TOMCAT_HOME/logs/catalina.out

Comment: I have added servlets to this location from my other computer. But while messing around I have copied the whole catalog from my old machine to this machine. Previously I have done the things that have been discussed here, unziped, sh.. etc. Worked. Everything on this machine is the same even paths. Thats probably why you see old logs. First I have installed java 7, but installing later tomcat 6 I realized that I need java 6. So installed it too.

Comment: I use this commend `sudo update-alternatives --config java` to determine which java to use, star shows which I am currently using: http://pastebin.com/7wzd5KU1. Catalina log: https://rapidshare.com/files/3694690578/catalina.out

Comment: Ok, run shutdown.sh, delete logs/catalina.log so that we're looking only at relevant data. Then set this up to run with the openjdk installation that I see in your alternatives list. This is done through changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable, the excellent ubuntu tomcat installation guide [here] (https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/tomcat.html) will show you how to do this. 
Then run startup.sh again. You've mentioned multiple times that you are running shutdown.sh kind of regularly. You are not shutting down the server before testing it, are you ? My apologies, just being thorough

Comment: catalina output: `./catalina.sh: 375: ./catalina.sh: .:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/java: not found` java there is a link to: '../jre/bin/java'

Comment: I don't think it can be fix. Oyrm you have already committed lots of your time helping me out and I just can't ask form more. Thank you for all your help I appreciate that very much but its seems like just a waste of time... Sorry for that.

Comment: No problem at all! I've installed Tomcat many times, and have occasionally had trouble with it. You may wish to simply start from scratch with a fresh download that has not been ported from another computer, and, if startup.sh shows no error, then look into firewall configurations and make sure you have opened port 8080

Answer (score 0):

We just installed Tomcat7 at work, and it rund great.

To install Tomcat 6, just unzip it with `tar -zxvf apache-tomcat-6.0.35.tar.gz`.  Then just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, switch to the directory were you unzipped, and run the command below.

```
sudo /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/startup.sh

sudo /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/shutdown.sh
```

To start as a service

```
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat6 start
```

In case you want another way of installing tomcat, tust press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo apt-cache search tomcat
sudo apt-get install tomcat6
sudo apt-get install tomcat6-admin
```

Comment: Exactly thats what I am doing - the commends and nothing. I think I am missing something.

Comment: We have OpenJDK Java 7.

Comment: Mitch how does this comply to my post? By the commands I meant startup.sh etc. No positive result.

Comment: Well, since you said that its not working, figured to check other items that can affect Tomcat.